# Recursive function in doctrine

Tags: recursion, doctrine-orm

I have a entity like this:

```
Person
  - id_person
  - name
  - child //self refering
```

If I query person entity in a recursive funcion it only returns me the first three levels. Do you know how to tell to doctrine that I want to get deep as many levels is required?

### Edit

**What was the problem?**
Using `$queryBuilder->getquery()->getResult(Query::HIDRATE_ARRAY);` is not the best way to make a recursive function, it should use the default hydration.

**How I resolve it?**
Using `$queryBuilder->getquery()->getResult();` and call the getters as @Andreas Linden say:  `$parent->getChild()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all associations will be lazy loaded when you access them from within your model 8if you don't define it to behave differently). so always use getter methods like `getChild()` which simply does `return $this->child;`

you can also left-join as many levels as you require so you won't generate thousands of queries (a single query for each child)

```
$query = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6')
    ->from('Entity\Person', 'p1')
    ->leftJoin('p1.child', 'p2')
    ->leftJoin('p2.child', 'p3')
    ->leftJoin('p3.child', 'p4')
    ->leftJoin('p4.child', 'p5')
    ->leftJoin('p5.child', 'p6')
    ->createQuery();
```

Comment: I don't know why the people just voted down without an explanation. Anyway.. Using `LeftJoin` is not a solution in this particular problem, because I don't know how deeper is my tree. And using `lazy` feach (my current configuration) only get the next three levels. For that reason I figure out that it should be a native Doctrine configuracion.

Comment: well, how do you access your assiciations? di you maybe use magic getters? I experienced the same problems when using magic getters for this... always use hardcoded getters.

Comment: The problem was the hydration mode! Thank you so much :)